# Is there a way to create a simple static image gallery in nginx without any third-party utilities?

Tags: nginx, image-gallery

I just want to be able to share a link to several images at once.

Answer (score 17):

The most simple way would be transforming file listings of nginx. You can do that by making nginx output listings as XML and then transform them using XSLT. Built-in module `ngx_http_autoindex_module` will do the former and usually dynamic module `ngx_http_xslt_filter_module` (aka `ngx_http_xslt_module`) will do the latter.

First, load the module in `nginx.conf` if needed:

```
load_module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";
```

Then, in your `sites-available/website.com`, add a location that tells nginx to transform the xml index using stlylesheet `gal.xslt` and pass a the name of the folder as a parameter.

```
location ~ /gal/([A-z]+)/$ {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format xml;
    xslt_string_param title $1;
    xslt_stylesheet gal.xslt;
    try_files $uri/ =404;
}
```

Finally, create `gal.xslt` in `/etc/nginx` that says,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <style>
        img, video {
            display: block;
            max-width: 20cm;
            max-height: 20cm;
            margin: 2mm;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            image-orientation: from-image;
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 20.4cm) {
            img {
                max-width: calc(100% - 4mm);
            }
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="list/file">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(' mp4 webm mkv avi wmv flv ogv ', concat(' ', substring-after(., '.'), ' '))">
                    <video controls="" src="{.}" alt="{.}" title="{.}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="{.}" alt="{.}" title="{.}"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now put some images into `/var/www/html/gal/foo`, restart nginx, navigate to `website.com/gal/foo` and you will see a simple but usable and responsive image gallery.

Comment: This is purely amazing! Thank you.

Comment: Beautiful and simple! the images were getting a 404 status code. I had to change `try_files $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` on Nginx 1.19

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @squirrel that's really simply yet powerful.

I've tweaked the xslt - this version gal.xslt below:

- Displays tumbnails in a grid, four columns wide.
- Resizes according to page size.
- Each image is click-able, so you can see the full size image.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <style>
      img {
           display: inline;
           width: 23%;    
           margin: 2mm;
           vertical-align: bottom;
      }
      @media all and (max-width: 20.4cm) {
          img {
              max-width: calc(100% - 4mm);
          }
      }
      body {
          margin: 0;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="list/file">
          <a href="{.}" title="click to enlarge">
              <img src="{.}" alt="{.}"/>
          </a>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```

Cheers,

Greg

Comment: Nice job, next step is to mix in the image filter module to generate and cache the thumbnails server side ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked a bit more: fancybox, thumbnail handling (with pregenerated thumbnails in the thumbs directory), ability to download all images as a browser generated zip file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
<html>
<head>
  <title><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" integrity="sha256-Vzbj7sDDS/woiFS3uNKo8eIuni59rjyNGtXfstRzStA=" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js" integrity="sha256-yt2kYMy0w8AbtF89WXb2P1rfjcP/HTHLT7097U8Y5b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jszip@3.1.5/dist/jszip.min.js" integrity="sha256-PZ/OvdXxEW1u3nuTAUCSjd4lyaoJ3UJpv/X11x2Gi5c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.5/dist/FileSaver.min.js" integrity="sha256-xoh0y6ov0WULfXcLMoaA6nZfszdgI8w2CEJ/3k8NBIE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>img { display: block; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></h1>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray; margin-bottom: 1rem;"></div>
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 2px; justify-content: center;">
<xsl:for-each select="list/file">
  <a href="{.}" data-fancybox="gallery">
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(/list/directory[text() = 'thumbs'])">
    <img loading="lazy" src="thumbs/{.}"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <img loading="lazy" src="{.}" height="200"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </a>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<script>
async function downloadAll() {
  const zip = JSZip();
  const folder = zip.folder('<xsl:value-of select="$title" />');
  const files = [
    <xsl:for-each select="list/file">
     '<xsl:value-of select="." />',
    </xsl:for-each>
  ];
  for(const i in files) {
    const file = files[i];
    const resp = await fetch(file);
    folder.file(file, resp.blob());
    $.fancybox.animate($.fancybox.getInstance().SlideShow.$progress.show(),{scaleX: i/files.length}, 0.1);
  }
  const zipFile = await zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'});
  saveAs(zipFile, '<xsl:value-of select="$title" />' + '.zip');
  $.fancybox.animate($.fancybox.getInstance().SlideShow.$progress.show(),{scaleX: 0}, 0.1); 
}

$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  buttons: [
    "zoom",
    "slideShow",
    "fullScreen",
    "download",
    "downloadAll",
    "close"
  ],
  btnTpl: {
    downloadAll:
      '<a class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--download" title="Download All" href="javascript:downloadAll()">' +
      '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 10v6m0 0l-3-3m3 3l3-3M3 17V7a2 2 0 012-2h6l2 2h6a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2z" style="fill:unset; stroke-width:2"/></svg>' +
      '</a>',
 },
});
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]')[0].click();
</script>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked also a bit more :-) and prepare generated configuration with the JS and CS. Main features are:

- images...

  - reading EXIF (via [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr))
  - show GPS on the Google Maps
  - view photo sphere panoramas (via [Photo Sphere Viewer](https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/))
  - an optional automatic image thumbnails with an optional cache
- videos (via [Plyr](https://plyr.io/)) *with optional auto conversion SRT subtitles to supported VTT*
- other files (just view and download)
- sharing link to the gallery
- sharing on social networks (via [shareon](https://shareon.js.org/))
- as lightbox is used [GLightbox](https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/)
- HTTP or HTTPS (Let's encrypt support - via external tools - [dehyhrated](https://dehydrated.io/) for example)
- custom gallery title/favicon and many more settings
- password access (via HTTP Basic Auth)

You can check it on https://github.com/forrest79/StaticNginxGallery.

Answer (score 0):

@squirrel's fantastic answer inspired me to bundle this all into a container for easy deployment. https://github.com/stuart23/image_server

Instructions are in the readme - it is as simple as:

```
docker build -t image_server .
docker run -p 8000:8000 -v /local/path/to/gallery:/var/www image_server
```